# pupetteer - get inner text returns JSHandle prefix

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I'm using this code to find an element and get its text:

```js
// helper method to find elements
async function findElementByText(page, tag, searchValue, conditionType) {
  const items = await page.$$(tag)
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let valueHandle = await items[i].getProperty('innerText');
    let itemText = await valueHandle.jsonValue();
    const text = getItemText(itemText);
    if(conditionType == 'contains'){
      if (text.indexOf(searchValue) !== -1) return items[i]
    }else if(conditionType == 'equals'){
      if (searchValue == text) return items[i]
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// find an element using helper
let searchResult = await findElementByText(parent, 'span', 'R$', 'contains')

// trying to get inner text
let itemText = await searchResult.getProperty('innerText');

console.log(itemText);
```

So the output is `JSHandle:R$ 594,60`. What is this JSHandle prefix?

I just want the text content. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `findElementByText` function is returning `items[i]` which is an `ElementHandle` returned by `page.$$(selector)`. You are then calling `getProperty` on this `ElementHandle`which in turn returns a `jsHandle`. When you `console.log` the `jsHandle` you get the `jsHandle` object. To get the text from the jsHandle you would have to get the JSON representation of the `jsHandle` by calling `jsonValue()`.

So in conclusion:

```js
let itemJsHandle = await searchResult.getProperty('innerText');
let itemText = await itemJsHandle.jsonValue();
```

Check out the puppeteer documentation: [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md).

Happy coding